# How to replace the value of a variable with previous calculated variable

Tags: javascript, loops, iteration

i'm trying to make a automated iteration for my thermodynamics class, but when i try to replace a value i obtained through calculation into the same equation and do it until its less than the requested error, but its not working. i think i don't really know how to do it... can someone help me?

```
 do {    
     vn = ((( r * t) / p)*( 1 + (b / v)+(c / (v ^ 2))+(d / (v ^ 3))));
     vn = v

     document.getElementById("termo").innerHTML = "The value of the real volume is:" + vn;
}
while ((v-vn) <= e )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to store the last value, `v = vn`.
Then you calculate the new value, `vn = ((( r * t) ...`.
Now you write out the new value, `document.getElementById(...`.
Then you compare the values and see if it's below the threshold, `while(...`.
If not, then do it all over again.

```
do {
  v = vn;
  vn = (((r * t) / p) * (1 + (b / v) + (c / (v ^ 2)) + (d / (v ^ 3))));

  document.getElementById("termo").innerHTML = "The value of the real volume is:" + vn;
} while (Math.abs(v-vn) > e);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6khxffuc/)
Mind though I've just set the initial values to some random numbers since I don't know what you are trying to calculate (but I'm guessing container volume regarding ideal gasses).

However, there is a possibility also that you've an error in your equation. I don't know of any thermodynamic equation using `XOR` (`^` is XOR in javascript). You probably meant `v to the second power` and `v to the third power`. Then your equation should look something like:

```
vn = (((r * t) / p) * (1 + (b / v) + (c / Math.pow(v, 2) + (d / Math.pow(v, 3)))));
```